# C++ Overloaded operator for a class with traits

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, traits

I'm getting to know traits in C++.
I've got these classes:

```
class Basic_traits {
public:
    ...
    static const int prec = 0;
};


template<typename T>
class Traits : public Basic_traits {
public:
    ...
};


class Temperature {
    double t;
public:
    Temperature(double temp = 50) : t(temp) {};
    double operator()() { return t; };
    Temperature& operator=(double temp) { t = temp; return *this; };
};


template<>
class Traits<Temperature> : public Basic_traits{
public:
    ...
    static const int prec = 2;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Temperature&) {
        os.precision(prec);
    }
};
```

What I want to do here is make an overloaded << operator for class Temperature, which will cout the t variable with the precision given in the prec trait. **Is this even possible? If so, then how do i do it? Is the operator supposed to be in the template?** I put it there cause that's where the prec is and class Temperature itself doesn't have anything to do with Basic_traits which contains a variable prec.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

My operator now looks like this:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Temperature&) {
    os.precision(Traits<Temperature>::prec);
    return os << (Temperature);
}
```

Comment: What are you not allowed to change?

Comment: @AndyG have in mind that I need to use overloaded () operator to return t from Temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which uses a base class template `Measurement` which defined the `ostream` operator, and uses `Traits<T>` to set the precision of the value it is outputting.

```
template<typename T>
struct Measurement
{
    double val;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Measurement<T>& measurement)
    {
        return os << std::setprecision(Traits<T>::prec) << measurement.val;
    }
};
```

We can then have different types of measurements, eg `Temperature`:

```
struct Temperature : Measurement<Temperature>
{
    Temperature(double v)
    {
        val = v;
    }
};
```

We can then specialise `Traits` for `Temperature`

```
template<>
struct Traits<Temperature>
{
    static const int prec = 2;
};
```

Now when you output anything which is a `Measurement`, it will use the specific traits for the derived class.

**Here is a full example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T>
struct Traits
{
    static const int prec = 0;
};

// our base class "Measurement"
template<typename T>
struct Measurement
{
    double val;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Measurement<T>& measurement)
    {
        return os << std::setprecision(Traits<T>::prec) << measurement.val;
    }
};

// a specific measurement type, Temperature
struct Temperature : Measurement<Temperature>
{
    Temperature(double v)
    {
        val = v;
    }
};

// specialise Traits for Temperature
template<>
struct Traits<Temperature>
{
    static const int prec = 2;
};

// a specific measurement type, Distance
struct Distance : Measurement<Distance>
{
    Distance(double v)
    {
        val = v;
    }
};

// specialise Traits for Distance
template<>
struct Traits<Distance>
{
    static const int prec = 4;
};

int main()
{
    Temperature temp { 5.2134 };
    Distance dist { 5.2134 };

    std::cout << temp << '\n';
    std::cout << dist << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to put that << operator in my Traits class and got three errors: error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&', see reference to class template instantiation 'Traits<T>' being compiled and missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int. It's also not where I want this operator. I want it either in class Temperature or template<>
class Traits<Temperature> : public Basic_traits. When I put it there I got one error, caused probably by how I get the t variable with () operator. I edited my post and put my current situation there.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example code I would suggest you typically wouldn't use a traits class, but instead just `setprecision(2)` *inside* the ostream operator for `Temperature`.

However, as you have mentioned you are more interested in getting to know traits, below is a somewhat contrived example showing a `Traits` primary class template, and 2 specialisations of that to alter the traits.

Start off by defining your primary `Traits` class template. Any type for which specialisation of `Traits` doesn't exist will use this.

```
template<typename T>
struct Traits
{
    static const int prec = 0;
};
```

We then specialise `Traits` for our various types. Here I do so for `Temperature` and `Distance`.

```
template<>
struct Traits<Temperature>
{
    static const int prec = 2;
};

template<>
struct Traits<Distance>
{
    static const int prec = 4;
};
```

We then use `Traits` in a generic setting, and select the appropriate traits for the provided type. Here I have a generic function `print` which will set the precision based on that provided by `Traits`

```
template<typename T>
void print(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(Traits<T>::prec) << t << '\n';
}
```

**Here is an example tying it all together:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template<typename T>
struct Traits
{
    static const int prec = 0;
};

struct Temperature
{
    double t;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Temperature& t)
    {
        return os << t.t;
    }
};

// specialise Traits for Temperature
template<>
struct Traits<Temperature>
{
    static const int prec = 2;
};

struct Distance
{
    double d;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Distance& d)
    {
        return os << d.d;
    }
};

// specialise Traits for Distance
template<>
struct Traits<Distance>
{
    static const int prec = 4;
};

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t)
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(Traits<T>::prec) << t << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Temperature temp { 5.2134 };
    Distance dist { 5.2134 };
    double d { 5.2134 };

    print(temp); // will use precision=2
    print(dist); // will use precision=4
    print(d);    // will use the fallback precision=0

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> $ ./a.out
> 5.2
> 5.213
> 5
> ```

Comment: The problem is I have to use what I've got (it's by my teacher and it's sort of a base for the exercise), you kinda did what I have, but changed some main things, which I cannot do. I always struggle with how to relate to different variables and so I found 'std::setprecision(Traits<T>::prec)' very useful. I now used it in my << operator, but still no idea how to get t. Edit: Just read again what you wrote and I must have missed a key line. I'll try again now.

Comment: Is there a way to use already existing overloaded () operator in my << overloaded operator? Looks like this so far:

 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Temprature&) {
  os.precision(Traits<Temperature>::precision);
  //??
 }

Comment: @Ania please see my other answer, perhaps this is more akin to what you're looking for?